# linux kernel preallocated non mapped virtual memory

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, memory-mapping

I have the following scenario:
qemu-kvm(guest) ---has virtual memory, get physical--->
virtio (send physical address to host) ---map physical to host virtual memory--->
host
The physical memory is preallocated. Is there a method to preallocate non mapped virtual memory on the host so that it won't have to search for free virtual address spaces?
Would this be a justifiable design concern if the buffers are pretty big?
The end result that I want is a pool of virtual address spaces to map received buffers.
After every job I want to unmap them and send them back the virtual address space to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

To reserve a virtual memory range without actually committing any physical pages to it, pass `PROT_NONE` as protection parameter to `mmap()`. Later on, you can use `mprotect()` on that range to make it readable/writable when necessary - the kernel will commit the physical pages on first access. When you're done, you can use `mprotect()` again to reset the protection status of the address range back to `PROT_NONE`.

Comment: m... My question is related to kernel space, where I can't work with mmap

Comment: You need to re-formulate your question then. Virtual address spaces in Linux are always associated with user space processes (via the `mm_struct` object). To attach a mapping to it, you need to allocate a `vm_area_struct` object, fill it up then do something like `insert_vm_struct(mm, vma)`, where `mm` points to the virtual address space of your process. When the user space process hits so defined virtual address range, the callback will be fired on the kernel side which will allow you to play whatever games with page mapping.